# Issues accessing Tkinter Radio Button CTRL var

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter, radio-button

I am having trouble getting the value of the selected radio button. Currently when I use the `.get()` function on my varible that the radio buttons use it returns "" nothing. If I use the message box without the `.get()` function then it returns `PY_VAR`x where x is the specific instance of the tkinter variable.

The radio buttons are using the variable properly, as seen by the fact that you can only select one radio button at a time, but I am not able to read the value properly. I want to read the current selection and put it into a different variable.

Below is abridged code (you are only seeing the radio button part of the program).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk

class init_system:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_vars = {"w_audiocodec": "Windows Media Audio 9.2 Lossless"}

class render_window:
    def __init__(self, height, width, window_title):
        self.root_window = Tk()
        w = width
        h = height
        ws = self.root_window.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
        hs = self.root_window.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
        self.root_window.title(window_title)
        self.root_window.minsize(width, height)
        self.root_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.master_dictionary = {"radio_ctrl": StringVar()}

    def new_button(self, button_text, button_command="", grid_row=0, grid_column=0, grid_sticky="NESW", grid_columnspan=1, grid_rowspan=1):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.root_window, text=button_text, command=button_command)
        self.button.grid(row=grid_row, column=grid_column, sticky=grid_sticky, columnspan=grid_columnspan, rowspan=grid_rowspan)
        self.responsive_grid(grid_row, grid_column)

    def new_label(self, label_text, text_alignment="center", grid_row=0, grid_column=0, grid_sticky="NESW", grid_columnspan=1, grid_rowspan=1):
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.root_window, text=label_text, anchor=text_alignment)
        self.label.grid(row=grid_row, column=grid_column, sticky=grid_sticky, columnspan=grid_columnspan, rowspan=grid_rowspan)
        self.responsive_grid(grid_row, grid_column)

    def responsive_grid(self, row_responsive=0, column_responsive=0, row_weight_num=1, column_weight_num=1):
        self.root_window.grid_columnconfigure(column_responsive, weight=column_weight_num)
        self.root_window.grid_rowconfigure(row_responsive, weight=row_weight_num)

    def new_radio_button(self, widget_text="Radio Button", radio_value="Radio Btn", radio_command="", grid_row=0, grid_column=0, grid_sticky="NESW", grid_columnspan=1, grid_rowspan=1):
        self.radio_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self.root_window, text=widget_text, variable=self.master_dictionary["radio_ctrl"], value=radio_value, command=radio_command)
        self.radio_button.grid(row=grid_row, column=grid_column, sticky=grid_sticky, columnspan=grid_columnspan, rowspan=grid_rowspan)
        self.responsive_grid(grid_row, grid_column)

class change_var_window(render_window):

    change_var_window_values = {"example_data_below": "Check it out!",
    "var_to_change": "show_ui",
    "toggle": False,
    "radio": False,
    "free_form":False,
    "line_one": "Current value of:",
    "line_two": "some varible name here passwed with a dicrionary",
    "Custom_Data_Bool": False,
    "Custom_Disable": "Enable me",
    "Custom_Enable": "Disable me",
    "radio_list": [("Radio Button 1", "btn_1"), ("Radio Button 2", "btn_2"), ("Radio Button 3", "btn_3")],
    "is_number": True}

    def save_radio_var(self):
        vars_system.init_vars[self.change_var_window_values["var_to_change"]] = self.master_dictionary["radio_ctrl"].get()
        messagebox.showinfo("debug", self.master_dictionary["radio_ctrl"].get()) 

    def create_change_var_window(self):
        self.new_label(self.change_var_window_values["line_one"], grid_columnspan=2)
        self.new_label(self.change_var_window_values["line_two"], grid_row=1, grid_columnspan=2)
        if self.change_var_window_values["radio"]:
            grid_placement = 2
            self.master_dictionary["radio_ctrl"] = StringVar()
            #self.master_dictionary["radio_ctrl"].set(vars_system.init_vars[self.change_var_window_values["var_to_change"]])
            for radio_name, value in self.change_var_window_values["radio_list"]:
                self.new_radio_button(widget_text=radio_name, radio_value=value, grid_row=grid_placement)
                grid_placement +=1
            grid_placement -=1
            self.new_button("Cancle", self.root_window.destroy, grid_row=grid_placement, grid_column=1)
            grid_placement -=1
            self.new_button("Save", self.save_radio_var, grid_row=grid_placement, grid_column=1)
            # Radio Requires:
            # "radio_list" "var_to_change"
        self.root_window.mainloop()

def radio_example():
    radio = change_var_window(300, 350, "Radio Select")
    radio.change_var_window_values.update({"free_form": False, "toggle": False, "radio": True, "var_to_change": "w_audiocodec", "line_one": "Current value of w_audiocodec:", "line_two": vars_system.init_vars["w_audiocodec"]})
    radio.change_var_window_values.update({"radio_list": [("Windows Media Audio 9.2", "Windows Media Audio 9.2"), ("Windows Media Audio 9.2 Lossless", "Windows Media Audio 9.2 Lossless"), ("Windows Media Audio 10 Professional", "Windows Media Audio 10 Professional")]})
    #main_window.root_window.withdraw()
    radio.create_change_var_window()

vars_system = init_system()

main_window = render_window(200, 250, "Main Window")
main_window.new_button("Radio Var", radio_example)

main_window.root_window.mainloop()
```

Thank you for taking time to look at this issue :-)

Comment: note: your code would be _much_ easier to understand if you followed PEP8. Specifically, your class names should begin with an uppercase character.

Comment: ok, I will keep that in mind as I finish this code. When I push it to the main program I will update to follow pep8 more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that you are creating more than one root window. You need to change your code so that you create exactly one instance of `Tk` for the life of your program.  Widgets and variables in one root cannot be shared with widgets and variables from another root window.

If you need more than one window, all but the root window need to be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Even if the variable being edited is in a different class instance? I will have to try this. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliotLabs: yes. You have to think of each root window as if it's in a separate process. That's not literally true, but conceptually it's fairly accurate. Each root window gets in independent Tcl interpreter with its own namespace.